# In Access 2010 I would like to find the % by MCO where data > 40. Not the % of total count by MCO, but rather % by count for each MCO

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

So, to be more clear (I hope) I want Count(where data>40 for a given MCO)/(Count(ID) for a given MCO) all by MCO.

```
    SELECT tblMCOs.MCOs, Count([tblMCOs].[ID])/(Select Count(tblMCOs.ID) 
    From tblMCOs)  AS MCOAvg
    FROM tblMCOs
    WHERE (((tblMCOs.data)>40))
    GROUP BY tblMCOs.MCOs
    ORDER BY tblMCOs.MCOs;
```

This is all using some mocked-up sandbox data for a larger project. So, I can do the math by hand see that what I'm getting now is Count(where data>40 for a given)/Total Count(ID) grouped by MCO.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to do something like this (apologies I don't have Access on my laptop at the moment so the syntax might need tweaking):

```
SELECT 
    tblMCOs.MCOs, 
    SUM(IIF(tblMCOs.data > 40, 1, 0)) / SUM(1)
FROM 
    tblMCOs
GROUP BY 
    tblMCOs.MCOs
ORDER BY 
    tblMCOs.MCOs;
```